# add block in observer magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, event-observer, blocks

I need to show labels(BACK ON STOCK) on product when they back to stock, 
for this I have added a observer

```
    <global>
       <events>
       <catalog_product_save_commit_after> 
         <observers>
           <Name_StockLabel_Model_Observer> 
             <type>singleton</type> 
             <class>Name_StockLabel_Model_Observer</class> 
             <method>backInStock</method>  
            </Name_StockLabel_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
       </catalog_product_save_commit_after>
     </events>
   </global>
```

and in observer am adding trying to add block

```
 public function backInStock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
        $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
        if ($stockItem->getCanBackInStock() && $stockItem->getQty() > $stockItem->getMinQty() && $stockItem->getIsInStock()){

            WANT TO ADD BLOCK HERE THAT WILL DISPLAY ON PRODUCT IN FRONTEND

        }
  }
```

Can anyone here advise me how can I add I block here

Comment: Hello @Daniel_12, did my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative way:

Create an attribute say `back_on_stock` with type `Yes/No`.

Change you event form  `catalog_product_save_commit_after` to `catalog_product_save_before`.

Now in observer you can set this new attribute value in your if condition, like:

```
$product->setBackOnStock(1);
return $this;
```

Now in Your `phtml`, you can check this attribute value and show label

Hope above will help!

Comment: my attribute is not getting save 
I am getting Null always, am updating product from backend

Comment: could you please share your code ?

Comment: ```function backInStock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $product->setBackInStock(1);
        //$product->save();
        return $this;
    }````

Comment: what is your attribute code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an observer for that.

Just add a conditon in your template (`catalog/product/view.phtml`), like this:

```
//$_product is Mage_Catalog_Model_Product object

<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus() && $_product->isAvailable()) :?>
    Stock is back
    <?php //echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your-block-id')->toHtml()?>
<?php endif;?>
```